# Is there a way to have a cell change the date after the date has passed?

Tags: sorting, date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to track my bills. I have `Due Date` in a cell and I want to have it check if the date has passed and change it to the next due date (some are monthly, some are quarterly and some are yearly). Is there a way to do this?

I've tried to use an `if` function that says *if the days until the dates are less than 0, then change the cell info*, but I can't figure out a function to use to change the cell.

```
=if('Sorted List'!D2<0,
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AbXrSbhhlGNluE4AuFH_bsP-a1bv1tlQMxswQJM7_pI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

paste in **A2** cell:

```
=SORT(FILTER('Bill List'!A2:D, 'Bill List'!B2:B>=TODAY()), 4, 1)
```

[image: 0]

after 4 days the Helth Insurance will disappear from list

Comment: Your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343547/google-sheets-automatically-increment-date-by-1-month?rq=1 is exactly what I needed. How could I do this for every other week(biweekly), every three months, and every year?